# Can you show an example of conformal geometric algebra being applied to synthetic geometry?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, soft-question, clifford-algebras

I have been studying conformal geometric recently where points, lines, etc are described as $n$-blades in geometric algebra. The notes I am studying claim that conformal geometric algebra can be applied to classical synthetic geometry making it significantly simpler but I have yet to see this in action.

Can you provide an example or any reference where conformal geometric algebra is being applied to prove a theorem in synthetic geometry?